# Major problems with Snap.svg loaded SVG graphics - selecting and animating path transforms on specific elements is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

UPDATED DESCRIPTION: Using Snap.svg - I'm trying to load an svg graphic, that contains several svg groups, the groups will be made up most of paths. I would like to select specific groups within the svg and then apply sequential path transform animations.

UPDATE #2: Per @Ian's suggestion I appended the other svg elements and they're appearing on screen but I still can't get them to animate. :)

So in this case I would like the 'forearm' to rotate, once its done rotating I want to animate the paths transforms as if the muscles were bulging (image below)

[image]

I've tried all the examples on snap.io and on SO but I can't get it to work. I'm racking my mind for a few hours and I still have yet to figure it out. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Disclaimer: I'm a bit of a JS n00b, so please be kind :)

Heres my html:

```
...
<body>
    <svg id="the_man"></svg>
</body>
...
```

Here's my svg - body.svg (from AI)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="body" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 400 400" enable-background="new 0 0 400 400" xml:space="preserve">
    <g id="arm">
        <path id="bicep" d="M337.889,188c0,0-36.11-35.556-98.333-32.222c-62.222,3.333-84.444,43.889-84.444,43.889l1.667,49.445
    c28.749,11.781,95.286,69.204,178.333,3.333L337.889,188z"/>
        <path id="forearm" d="M174.333,250.938c0,0,19.659-36.111,17.816-98.333c-1.844-62.223-24.267-84.445-24.267-84.445l-27.338,1.667
    c-6.514,28.749-38.263,95.286-1.843,178.334L174.333,250.938z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Finally, heres my JS.

**UPDATE**

**Thank you @Robert Longson that helped to make my svgs, those must have been some js comments that slipped in there :) But I'm still having trouble get the path transform animations**

**Thanks to @Ian for the suggestion but I still cant get it to work-what am I missing?**

```
(function($) {

    'use strict';

    // grab the empty svg element in the html
    var s = Snap(800,600);

    // animate rotate the forearm graphic
    var anim1 = function() {
        forearm.animate({
            'transform': 'r45,320,120'
        }, 1000, mina.linear, anim2);
    };

    // animate from the svg images current path coordinates top the ones below
    var anim2 = function() {
        bicep.animate({
            d: 'M337.889,188c-12.064-11.708-28.073-93.482-89.777-92.889c-62.222,3.333-93,104.555-93,104.555l1.667,49.445 c29.608,30.553,96.669,99.406,178.333,3.333L337.889,188z'
        }, 1000, mina.bounce, anim3);
    };

    // animate from the svg images current path coordinates top the ones below
    var anim3 = function() {
        forearm.animate({
            d: 'M174.333,250.938c0,0,19.659-36.111,17.816-98.333c-25.316-59.032-31.731-75.007-24.267-84.445l-27.338,1.667 c-35.496,57.849-82.325,139.528-1.843,178.334L174.333,250.938z'
        }, 1000, mina.bounce);
    };

    // load the svg and grab the #arm and its inner elemmnts
    Snap.load('body.svg', function(f) {
        var arm = f.select('#arm'),
            forearm = f.select('#forearm'),
            bicep = f.select('#bicep');
        s.append(arm);
        s.append(forearm);
        s.append(bicep);
        anim1();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: // are not valid path characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its worth trying to break it down into a smaller chunk on a jsfiddle first.

However, it initially looks like you are doing a Snap.load() which is asynchronous, and then calling an animation before its probably loaded. You haven't really said what specific problems you are having.

So rather than..

```
Snap.load('body.svg', function(f) {
    select stuff...
    add stuff...
});

animateStuff();
```

You probably want to do..

```
 Snap.load('body.svg', function(f) {
    select stuff...
    add stuff...
    animateStuff();
});
```

Otherwise when you call the animate function, the load won't have actually finished, so it wouldn't surprise me if you get some undefined type messages in your console log.

Comment: Thanks @Ian, trying that now. I'll post an update in a few min.

Comment: You need to put a fiddle up, as I think there's a few errors. For example also it looks like you append 'arm', but never append 'bicep', so it can't animate that.

Comment: k, I'll put a fiddle together now

Comment: I've answered the one at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678159/how-do-you-animate-path-morphs-inside-of-loaded-svg-with-snap-svg I would probably mark one of them as a duplicate.